# Odd batch escape character problem

Tags: mysql, batch-file, escaping

I'm trying to execute this mysql command from a batch file:

```
mysql -f -utest -ppass db < alter1.sql
```

However, < is an escape character. I tried nesting it in double-quotes, but the double quotes end up appearing as part of the command.

I even put a carrot (^) in front of it, LOOKS fine in the prompt window, but mysql still gets that ^ passed to it, and doesn't execute the command.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What you've written is exactly what you'd want in a windows .bat file.  How are you trying to get it into the .bat file?  With an "echo" command?

Comment: **<** is **not** an escape character, it is a redirection character, windows or linux.   
What is the context? Is this mySQL on windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
type alter1.sql | mysql -f -utest -ppass db
```